# What theme does NOOBS use and how can I apply it to LXDE?

Tags: raspbian, lxde, noobs

[NOOBS](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/4100) has a very clean and neat theme which has better typography, spacing, control look and an overall better color scheme than any of the themes available in LXDE under Raspbian, including Redmond.

[image: NOOBS looks good]

As you can see below, a typical Raspbian LXDE desktop looks very different from NOOBS.

[image]

I tried all the Openbox themes too, but neither combination of themes resulted in anything that looked like NOOBS.

What WM is the NOOBS installer using? What theme is it using? How can I make my LXDE look and feel exactly like this? The font looks like Tahoma, but how do I go about mimicking the rest of the look on my Raspbian installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Qt/KDE theme called 'Plastik' http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qplastiquestyle.html .

It's only availiable to a programs which was buit with Qt framework.
Openbox is using it's own style system and LXDE apps is GTK based, so you can't just use this theme. You should look for a GTK theme engine that would look good for you.